# applying filter to multiple embedded tableau dashboards

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I have 2 Tableau dashboards embedded onto a webpage, each using the Embed Code from clicking the "share" button on Tableau Public. I have a filter on the 1st dashboard that I would also like to apply to the 2nd when clicked. What is the easiest way to do so?

Here is my current code:

```
<section class="py-5">
                <div class="container px-5">
                    <h1 class="fw-bolder fs-5 mb-4">Heart Disease Study Data Analysis</h1>
                    <div class="card border-0 shadow rounded-3 overflow-hidden">
                        <!-- Dashboard 1 div -->
                        <div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1623283782551' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt='Dashboard ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;He&#47;HeartDiseaseStudyAnalysis&#47;Dashboard&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript>
                            <object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'>
                                <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> 
                                <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' />
                                <param name='name' value='HeartDiseaseStudyAnalysis&#47;Dashboard' />
                                <param name='tabs' value='no' />
                                <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
                                <param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;He&#47;HeartDiseaseStudyAnalysis&#47;Dashboard&#47;1.png' /> 
                                <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' />
                                <param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
                                <param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='language' value='en-US' />
                            </object>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            <!-- </section> -->
 
            <!-- <section class="py-5"> -->
                <!-- <div class="container px-5"> -->
                    <!-- <h1 class="fw-bolder fs-5 mb-4">Heart Disease Study Data Analysis</h1> -->
                    <div class="card border-0 shadow rounded-3 overflow-hidden">
                        <!-- Dashboard 2 div -->
                        <div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1623287413728' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt='Dashboard 2 ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;He&#47;HeartDiseaseStudyAnalysis&#47;Dashboard2&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript>
                            <object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'>
                                <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' />
                                <param name='name' value='HeartDiseaseStudyAnalysis&#47;Dashboard2' />
                                <param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
                                <param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;He&#47;HeartDiseaseStudyAnalysis&#47;Dashboard2&#47;1.png' /> 
                                <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' />
                                <param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
                                <param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='language' value='en-US' />
                            </object>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        
        <!-- Dashboard 1 js -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>                    
            var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1623283782551');                    
            var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    
            if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';} 
            else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';} 
            else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1477px';}                     
            var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
            scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    
            vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                
        </script>
 
        <!-- Dashboard 2 js -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>                    
            var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1623287413728');                    
            var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    
            if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';} 
            else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';} 
            else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1427px';}                     
            var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
            scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    
            vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the embed code from the share option in Tableau Server. If you want to have persistent filters apply across dashboards, you'll need to leverage the Tableau Javascript API, **not the embed option**. You can find a tutorial on including the API and filtering workbooks here: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_filtering.htm